# module does not have the attribute... subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS

Tags: python

This ought to be a very simple question. From the documentation, there's a constant used in the subprocess package run function, subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS.

Here's a more detailed programn that proves the python version number:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
print("Version info.")
print (sys.version_info)

import subprocess
print(subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)
```

Yet I get with this program:

```
python3 foo.py 
Python version
3.9.9 (main, Nov 16 2021, 03:05:18) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my_ros_data/rosutils/old/foo.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)
AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'DETACHED_PROCESS'
```

I agree that it looked like a version problem but it seems that I've conclusively demonstrated that it's something else.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Is it in windows ?

Comment: Ubuntu. Python 3.6.9.

Comment: According to the documentation, you need version 3.7 or above.

Comment: Wait a minute: playing around based on googling, I got this error message: "ValueError: creationflags is only supported on Windows platforms". Could it be that this constant DETACHED_PROCESS is not even defined on ubuntu at all?

Comment: After doing some research as well, I found an article that says it's Windows-only as well, so unfortunately it's probably not available for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using Windows Try this.**

```
import sys
from subprocess import DETACHED_PROCESS
from subprocess import Pope
print("Python version")
print(sys.version)
print("Version info.")
print(sys.version_info)
Proc = []
data = Popen(["hello"], creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS, shell=True)
Proc.append(data)
print(data)
```

if you are using linux

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['nc', '-l', '8888'],
                 cwd="/",
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
 print(p)
```

Comment: Thanks and welcome! Can you help me understand why that works? And what if I want to look at say the first 10 seconds of stdout and then continue my code as the sunbprocess also stays alive? (I am doing an ssh to a launch a program which just runs until it is killed.

Answer (score 0):

The `DETACHED_PROCESS` property was added to subprocess in Python version 3.7. Update Python to the latest version and it should work.

Comment: I've updated the main question with a slightly longer program which shows that I am using Python 3.9. Could the library be a different version or something like that?